# Android Studio : ImageButton image/background flash

Tags: android, flash, animation, android-animation, android-imagebutton

Please let me know, is there an easy way to flash/toggle the background or image of an `ImageButton` in Android?

I am basically trying to let the user know visually when to perform a click action on an `ImageButton`. So flashing the button would help.

I've tried to research the topic & have not come up with anything.  The only thing that comes to mind is to implement a `Timer` with a `Handler` to toggle between the two drawable assets. But that seems overkill!

Appreciate you guys taking it easy on this Android Newbie.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest you to use `animation-list` as background to your `ImageButton`.

1) Create a `flash_background.xml` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<animation-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:oneshot="false">

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/first_background" android:duration="200" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/second_background" android:duration="200" />

</animation-list>
```

2) Then from code

```
yourButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.flash_background);
AnimationDrawable anim = (AnimationDrawable) yourButton.getBackground();
anim.start();
```

**Notice:**

- You can play with `android:duration` to speed up/down the animation.

Comment: Thank you Rami! Awesome implementation!  It worked just like I imagined.

Answer (score 0):

You can set an Backgorund to that image with any color you want to be the flash color , and after that you can make padding bottom , up ,right and left to that image when the user click the button to make that image surround the main image. If you don't know how to implement that you can comment to add some code :)

Comment: Appreciate your answer.  Rami's answer below worked better.